# Why does Visual Studio debugger shows a long hex value for an int?

Tags: c#, debugging, integer, visual-studio-2013, long-integer

While debugging I've come across this interesting behavior :

The hex value string of `a` is twice as long as the others.

[image]

Can you tell why is this happening ?

Comment: Is this C#?  You should add a language tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking the debugger to evaluate the expression for you.  It now acts like a compiler, converting the watch expression you entered into code and running that code to display the result.    It thinks that `0xff000000` is a literal of type *long*, which is a fair call since *int* cannot store that value, it is larger than Int32.MaxValue.  So it evaluates the >> operator with *long* arguments, converting the `i` value to *long* first.  The result is of course *long* as well.

Since you didn't otherwise cast to smaller type, like you did in your code, the debugger displays the result (when switched to hexadecimal output) as a long with 64 bits, 16 hex digits.

The other expressions don't behave that way, the literals used in them are smaller than Int32.MaxValue so are evaluated with *int* arguments, producing a 32 bit result, 8 hex digits.

Notable perhaps is that the debugger's expression evaluator is close, but not identical to the C# compiler's evaluator.  Not an issue here, but it can matter in some cases.  This may change some day when the Roslyn project finally ships.